# How to write this async method using Observables only?

Tags: typescript, rxjs5

How can I write this code without `Promise`, only using `Observable`?

```
  private method(auth: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(value => resolve(value));
    })
  }
```

Currently it returns a `Promise<any>`, I'd like to make it return an `Observable<any>`... [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) has this signature:

```
onAuthStateChanged(nextOrObserver, error, completed) returns function()
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You only want it to be resolved once?

Comment: Yes, once observable emits a value I want to use that value in other places...

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to ignore all but the first event emitted by the observable? Provide an example, with events emitted by the source observable, and events emitted by the observable you want as result. Given your description above, my gues is that you just need `return observable;`

Comment: @JBNizet You're right, this is completely useless method (; I'm actually using [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged), that has very similar signature to observable... I'll update the question